# history.pushstate jquery back button not loading prev content

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I am trying to [implement history.pushstate with jQuery as described](http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/)

This is the following code I have:

```
container = $(".loadContent");
currentItem = null;
$(".list-group a").each(function (index) {
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.hasClass("active")) {
        currentItem = item;
    }
    item.on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        history.pushState({}, '', $(this).attr("href"));
        $(".heightDiv").css("height", divheight);
        if (currentItem == item) return;
        $(".content").empty();
        $(".loading").css("height", divheight).show();
        url = this.href + " .content";
        if (currentItem) currentItem.removeClass("active");
        currentItem = item.addClass("active");
        container.load(url, function(){$(".loading").hide();});
        return false;
    });
});

loadPage = function(href) {
  container.load(href + " .content");
};

$(window).on("popstate", function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
    loadPage(location.href);
  }
});
```

The address bar it is picking up the correct address, however when I hit the back button, the address bar gets back correctly but the previous content it is not loaded