# How to handle browser back/next button when loading content with ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tried BBQ and history.pushstate and I had issues with both. See my other questions here on stack for [history.pushstate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277054/history-pushstate-jquery-back-button-not-loading-prev-content) and [using bbq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26278107/history-change-using-bbq-causes-content-to-constaly-reload-randomly)

With this code I am basically loading content within a specific div, replacing the old content each time we click on a link. I am trying to have the browser address change when content is loaded and be able to hit the back or previous button on the browser itself to reload the content

```
divheight = $(".heightDiv").innerHeight();
container = $(".loadContent");
currentItem = null;
$(".list-group a").each(function () {
    var item = $(this);
    if (item.hasClass("active")) {
        currentItem = item;
    }
    item.on("click", function() {
        $(".heightDiv").css("height", divheight);
        if (currentItem == item) return;
        $(".content").empty();
        $(".loading").css("height", divheight).show();
        url = this.href + " .content";
        if (currentItem) currentItem.removeClass("active");
        currentItem = item.addClass("active");
        container.load(url, function() {
            $(".loading").hide();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: If you had issues with both, I say delete the question's u created. And ensure only one is maintained :)

Comment: Please refer to this Link (http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/).

Comment: @LearningNeverStops Why? Other users may find beneficial the answer in regards of each one. This question may lead to a more general way without to use those methods.

Comment: @rob.m then ensure you add up your finding in that as an answer and not just conclude it inside a question. After all, a finding scenario is an answer. And that also is  a real help :)

Comment: @LearningNeverStops what findings? Each questions has directs links to the source. Definitly will make my own answer once I get the solution if no one will. Do you have it btw? :)

Comment: haa :) I was a bit confused when you said, you have issues with their usage and thought it wont work out and is not a correct way :)

Comment: @LearningNeverStops :) Nope i am pretty sure I am doing something wrong but they do work if correctly used. maybe just some mistake I'm doing somehow and hoping someone will address it. meanwhile i'm trying myself to solve it :P